# Mysql 5.7 does not support DENSE_RANK()

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using `DENSE_RANK()` for alloting rank, but my MYSQL version is 5.7 that does not support `DENSE_RANK()`

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY (IFNULL((SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(lt.dispatch_date,t.received_at)<=2 OR DATEDIFF(t.received_at,t.created_at) <= 2  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
/(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(lt.dispatch_date,t.received_at)<=2 OR DATEDIFF(t.received_at,t.created_at) <= 2  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
+SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(lt.dispatch_date,t.received_at)>2 OR DATEDIFF(t.received_at,t.created_at) > 2  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)))
*100,0)+(IFNULL((IFNULL(SUM(DATEDIFF(d.created_at,t.received_at) <= 2),0)/(IFNULL(SUM(DATEDIFF(d.created_at,t.received_at) <= 2),0)+
IFNULL(SUM(DATEDIFF(d.created_at,t.received_at) > 2),0))),0)*100))/2 DESC) dens_rank
```

expecting

[image: 1]

Comment: Correct! A [mcve] is a great start if you need SQL assistance.

Comment: Just upgrade it, 5.7 is old and its support will end this year.

Comment: Maybe it is time to upgrade to MySQL 8? It has been around for rather a long time now ([MySQL 8.0.11 (2018-04-19, General Availability)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-11.html)).

Comment: MySQL 5.7 reaches end of life 8 months from now. Time to upgrade.

Comment: I don't have option to upgrade only with 5.7 only I  have to work with. So any logic which can make me to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your observation is correct. You need to upgrade to MySQL 8 if you want to use `DENSE_RANK()`

Comment: any other option apart from upgrading ?
I don't have option to upgrade. On 5.7 only I  have to work with. So any logic which can make me to overcome this issue.